# Appropriate label for a button that takes a user to an item?

Tags: usability, buttons, labels

I have a simple setup for this scenario...

1. A page that lists all "playing seasons".
2. Each season in the list has two buttons on the far right, an "Open" and a "Delete" button
3. The "Open" button takes the user to a second page that loads that specific season and provides detailed information, as well as the ability to edit the season.

My question is around the button label "Open". "Opening" a season could actually confuse a user, because in this domain "Opening" a season is a real thing. You open or close a playing season.

"Edit" doesn't seem appropriate, because the second page lets you do much more than edit. You can see details, statistics, and edit if you want to.

View isn't really great...it seems to "vague" of a term, and you can do more than "view" on that page.

Ideas? What's a good word for a button that takes the user to an instance of an item from a list of items?

---

**EDIT**

I'm inclined *not* to have a button for this, but instead to open the season when the user clicks the row. My concern there is that it's not entirely obvious at first that the user can click the row to go to that particular season.

Or maybe "Details"?

Comment: I'd go with your initial inclination. If the user is presented with a list of things, it's common to touch on an item to see more. To me a "view" button is clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"view" seems logical - but hard to call without knowing what else you can do on the page.

Otherwise "details" or even "view details" would make sense.

Comment: Went with "Details" hyperlink

Comment: sounds good to me!

Answer (score 1):

Few thoughts:

1) Think about this - for editing something, you first need to be able to view it right? So there is no issue, in not worrying about telling user upfront about the edit. Progressive disclosure is better rather than trying to tell all at once. User will go the view page, and then a clear mention or hint that he can edit is sufficient.

2) In terms of terminology: How about, "More details >" OR even a nicely designed ">" button, that comes up on hovering each row could do.

3) Its always good to provide affordances that users can pick up - hence just relying on the fact that user will click the row itself (without any button, indication), might not be a good idea.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Amit! Thanks for the ideas. Agree with progressive disclosure but if their task is to edit, view button might throw them off. More details with the arrow is a great idea. Agreed on just clicking the row- it doesn't provide an affordance. I'm actually leaning towards making it a link, since that really indicates going somewhere.